# Refresh Elements ListView QML

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qml, kdevelop

Does anyone know how to force a refresh ListView in QML.
The problem when I execute my program on a real device, I have buttons that multiply and I have to move the scroll barr so that they disappear.

Yet I do not have this problem when I execute the program on Kdev.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

are you using QML ListModel?, when you modify the ListModel, changes are reflected in the ListView, you should look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html)